# Get or Create in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

Using spring boot if how I can implement this logic (Get or Create)
Post request I will pass the student details if the student email exist return simple message "email already exist" and if not create new student record

I am using JpaRepository for my DB connection and I do have
Student class has the student structure data setter getter ...etc.
StudentController has registerNewStudent calls studentService.addNewStudent
StudentService has the addNewStudent method

addNewStudent should include some logic to check if the student email exist and if not it should create

What do you think ?

Comment: Do JpaRepository by default has something to handle?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a findByEmail method using JpaRepository. This method means select * from student where email="passedValue". If student with this email exits this method will return that student otherwise it will return null.

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,String> {

Student findByEmail(String email); }
```

And then use this method:

```
public void saveStudent(Student student) {
    Student savedStudent = studentRepository.findByEmail(student.getEmail());
    if (savedStudent != null) {
        System.out.println("email already exist");
    } else {
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this of course solved thanks for sharing